# iphone - Nav-bar app crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, crash, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar controller app with two tabs.  One of my tabs uses a navigation controller.
The navigation controller that I made for this resides in View A.   View A acts solely as a controller and automatically pushes View B which in turn pushes view C which pushes View D.

I want the next view to be View B, so I used

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
int i=0;
while (! [[[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] nibName] 
        isEqualToString:@"ViewBController"]
        && i < [viewControllers count]) 
             i++;
```

to get the view I want (in some cases the order of the views may change so I don't want to hardcode it) 
and then

```
self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] animated:NO];
```

to get back to view B

My issue is that the app crashes at this point.  Well technically it crashes after it deallocs View C (I put nslogs there to figure that out).

I have no idea what my issue can be?  Can anyone provide insight?

EDIT: I also tried making a new view controller, View E, and pushing that and it still crashes

Comment: You should post the crash logs. It could be absolutely anything...

Comment: That's my issue, there are no crash logs, it just stops running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem, it turned out not to be a navigation issue.

Before switching views I had an alert that I set to autorelease, and then I also released it.
I figured this out by using NSZombie, which is awesome.

For anyone who needs the reference check this out:
http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Answer (score 0):

First, a clarification... When you say that your nav controller resides "in View A" what exactly do you mean? Do you mean it is the View Controller contained on the first tab?

So far it looks like you might have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use a navigation controller. They aren't supposed to be loaded so that you can flipped through to whichever one you want. Each view controller in the navigation controller should be a new screen that your user has chosen to navigate to. It sounds like you are trying to populate the nav controller with a bunch of view controllers and then push or pop to one of them in the middle, but that's not really how it works.

Here is a video explaining how to use a UINavigationController, perhaps it will help. http://vimeo.com/2371881

Comment: Yes, View A is the view controller that resides in the first tab.

I'm not trying to pop and push to the middle of the nav controller.  I have a set flow, and then I want the user to be brought back to the beginning of the flow.

Comment: I've been thinking about what you said and maybe I shouldn't be using a navigationController for what I'm doing, since I want to control the flow and it's not exactly linear.  If that's the case then how do I present a new view without using presentModalViewController, since I want to still see the tabs?

Comment: Well, that's always a tough question when it comes to the design of an app without a linear flow. But what you can do it just swap out the viewControllers in the first tab. You can get the array of view controllers from -viewControllers property on the UITabBarController, then replace the view controller for that tab and set the -viewControllers property again with the new array. I wouldn't necessarily _recommend_ it.. but it would work.